# Claiming t-shirt of Mathematics Stack Exchange after months pass

Tags: discussion, support, merchandise

I got the following email about a year ago from Stack Exchange:

[image]

After a long consideration, I decided to accept the gift but when I clicked the given link I couldn't access the Google Form since I've not been granted a permission from the owner's organization. What should I do to get the t-shirt? Can I still claim the t-shirt after months pass?

Comment: "After a long consideration" - how long? Month? I assume they did not mean to wait for long weeks for people to decide, so they closed the form.

Comment: I need months to think since I have lots of problems during my active participation on Math SE. I didn't blame the SE Team for closing the form.

Comment: OK, fair enough, glad you understand you can't expect them to wait for you. As Patrick says in the answer, you really better discuss it directly with the team via emails, not here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would contact the SE team using the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page. Explain the situation and see what they can do.

That is the best option available now. You may need to be a little patient since an answer can take some days.